# Expansion Tile e ListView

Tags: dart, flutter

Estou tentando criar esse [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJNkO.png) para um app, usei um expansion tile dentro de um Card e uma listView abaixo, porém quando eu abro o expansionTile, se bater no fundo da tela acontesse [isso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE2aU.jpg) e se a listView tiver muitos tiles acontece [isso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrumO.jpg), não estou conseguindo de forma alguma resolver esse problema.

Segue meu código abaixo:

```
     class HomeState extends State<Teste>{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text (""),
          ),
            body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CardList(),
                  MyList()
                ],
              ),
            ),
        );
      }
    }

    Widget CardList(){
      return new Flexible(
          child: Card(
            elevation: 5,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0xC8, 0xF4, 0xF2),
            child: ExpansionTile(
              title: Text("Periodo",
                style: new TextStyle(
                ),textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListaPeriodos(10)
              ],
            ),
          )
      );
    }

Widget MyList(){
  return new ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return new ListTile(
        title: new Text(
          "Texto",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            color: Colors.black45
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    itemCount: 15,
  );
}
```

Comment: Pelo que entendo seu conteúdo está transbordando do tamanho possível de tela. Tente colocar sua árvore de Widgets em um SingleChildScrollView().

Comment: Obrigado, eu fiz isso e funcionou visualmente, porem agora eu não consigo rolar a pagina, só se eu passar o dedo pela bordinha da tela. Minha ideia é que esse expansionTile fique fixo na tela, enquanto a lista abaixo seja possível de rolar, as opções da lista serão mostradas de acordo como o que é selecionado no expansionTile.

Comment: Entendi, no caso seu conteúdo completo da tela poderá ser "scrollado" não é isso? e no caso de o Tile e a lista ser maior que a tela vc fará o "scroll" nos dois widgets? Pq eu fiquei pensando no seu layout e acho que o seletor que vc apresentou ficaria com o conteúdo melhor apresentado em um Dialog que exibisse suas opções. Assim apenas a lista teria o scroll. Fica a sugestão.

Answer (score 1):

Os erros ocorrem, pois pelo fato de você não ter indicado uma altura limite da `ListView` e ela estar dentro da `Column` do `ExpansionTile`, ela cresce de acordo com a quantidade de itens, dessa forma em algum momento ultrapassa o limite da tela e acontece o erro.

Uma solução possível é envolver sua `ListView` em um `Container` de altura limitada com uma altura menor que a da tela inteira, por exemplo 200, permitindo assim scrollar tanto a lista (Dentro desses 200), como a tela.

Você limitar a altura da `ListView` utilizando o `Container` evita o erro e ativa o scroll da própria ListView , sem necessidade de implementar um `SingleChildScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Caso não tenha conseguido ajustar o scroll da ListView dentro do ExpansionTile, aconselho adicionar a seguinte linha dentro do seu ListView.builder:

controller: ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true)

O "ScrollController" te permite adicionar um controlador que faz com que sua lista de widgets reaja de acordo com as interações que você fizer na tela, e o argumento "keepScrollOffset: true" libera o comportamento de scroll ao tocar em qualquer item de sua lista.

Resumindo, dessa forma você conseguirá "scrollar" tocando em qualquer parte da sua lista, e não somente no ExpansionTile.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).